# How can I increase/decrease the brightness of UIImage and I need to save the resultant image?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I've an image , I want to change its brightness and I need to save the resultant image obtained from the actual image, how can I do it. I want to increase the brightness using a UIslider?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Get the code from the Github for `UIImage` category [here](https://github.com/Nyx0uf/NYXImagesKit).

To brighten the image, write the code as below:

```
//brighten value can be obtained from slider change event from -255 to 255.
UIImage* brightImage = [originalImage brightenWithValue:sliderValue];

//Convert image into data
NSData *brightImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(brightImage);

//Get the path of Documents directory and store the data object to proper file
```

Comment: This category is taking too much memory .

Answer (score -1):

Here's the sample code and explanation about implementing simple image processing filters (Brightness, Contrast, Saturation, Hue rotation, Sharpness) using OpenGL ES1.1.
 I recommend you this apple's official [link here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/GLImageProcessing/Introduction/Intro.html)