# How to adjust brightness contrast saturation in swift with a UISlider

Tags: swift, uislider, cifilter, ciimage

I have been looking for the past couple of days on how to implement a filter to a `UIImage` by manually manipulating the brightness, contrast, highlight, shadows, warmth and etc.. using a `UISlider`?

Here is my code that is currently being used to adjust the brightness..

```
let currentValue = Int(editPictureView.sliderView.value)
editPictureView.currentPropertyValue.text = String(currentValue) + " "    
brightnessFilter.setValue(NSNumber(value: editPictureView.sliderView.value), forKey: "inputBrightness")
outputImage = brightnessFilter.outputImage!
//let imageRef = context.createCGImage(outputImage, from: outputImage.extent)
newUIImage = UIImage(ciImage: outputImage)
editPictureView.selectedImageToEdit.image = newUIImage;
```

But I receive an error that states that it found a `nil` while unwrapping.
All I am asking is for you to share that feeling you felt when you solved this problem the first time, and if you can explain it you would also understand it better yourself, or at least such as the story goes.
But honestly thank you in advance.

Comment: What's `brightnessFilter`? Please include its declaration in the question. Also, do not ever use force unwrapping of optionals unless you are 100% they will have a non-nil value by the time you unwrap them.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080435/how-can-i-increase-decrease-the-brightness-of-uiimage-and-i-need-to-save-the-res

Comment: By far, the most efficient way - performance in particular - is to use (1) three separate sliders, one each for brightness, saturation, and contrast with (2) with the CoreImage CIColorControls (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIColorControls), and (3) display the CIImage output using a `GLKView`, which uses the GPU. The link above has a comment on the answer about memory consumption, and using a `UIImage` or anything UIKit related will suffer from poor performance.

Answer (score 3):

```
func imageBrightness(imgView : UIImageView , sliderValue : CGFloat, image: UIImage){
        let aCGImage = image.cgImage
        aCIImage = CIImage(cgImage: aCGImage!)
        context = CIContext(options: nil)
        brightnessFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorControls")
        brightnessFilter.setValue(aCIImage, forKey: "inputImage")

        brightnessFilter.setValue(sliderValue, forKey: "inputBrightness")
        outputImage = brightnessFilter.outputImage!
        let cgimg = context.createCGImage(outputImage, from: outputImage.extent)
        newUIImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgimg!)
        imgView.image = newUIImage
        print("brightness")
    }
```

Call this method and pass slider value and image as follows:
imageBrightnessEdit(imgView: self.imgView, sliderValue: CGFloat(value), image: imgSelected)

For contrast:

```
func imageContrast(imgView : UIImageView , sliderValue : CGFloat, image: UIImage){

        let aUIImage = image
        let aCGImage = aUIImage.cgImage

        aCIImage = CIImage(cgImage: aCGImage!)
        context = CIContext(options: nil)
        contrastFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorControls")
        contrastFilter.setValue(aCIImage, forKey: "inputImage")

        aCIImage = CIImage(cgImage: aCGImage!)
        context = CIContext(options: nil)
        contrastFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorControls")
        contrastFilter.setValue(aCIImage, forKey: "inputImage")
        contrastFilter.setValue(sliderValue, forKey: "inputContrast")
        outputImage = contrastFilter.outputImage!
        let cgimg = context.createCGImage(outputImage, from: outputImage.extent)
        newUIImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgimg!)
        imgView.image = newUIImage
        print("contrast")

    }
```

Comment: Ok I am having a problem right now, I am using a UISlider to change the brightness and the contrast except that after implementing the given code above my UISlider is lagging, would you mind giving me a couple of recommendations as to how I would be able to fix this.

Comment: May be resolution of your imgae is high. You can use dispatch thread.